# Problema com Array vazio com mysql e nodejs

Tags: mysql, array, node.js, npm

Essa é a action que é ativada ao carregar a pagina: Nela eu recebo como resultado o seguinte array abaixo. Meu problema é, quando não tem nenhum registro o ARRAY retorna vazio, não consigo passar um parametro para o INPUT.

**Ex.: input(value="#{data[0][0].alimentacao || 0}")**

Se não encontrar o registro preenche com zero, porém antes disso já apresenta erro por não encontrar o parametro data[0][0].alimentacao e consequentemente não carrega a página.

No BD, já tentei setar os campos como default NULL e default 0 e mesmo assim não retorna os campos.

Se eu inserir dados manualmente, funciona perfeitamente.

```
 **[ [],** [{"nNomes":0,"salariosMembros":null}], [{"salarioTitular":null}] ]

getDespesa: function(req,res){
 var _id = req.params.id;

 db.query('SELECT * FROM despesas WHERE idCliente = ?; 
           SELECT COUNT(nomeCompleto) as nNomes, SUM(ultimosalario) as salariosMembros FROM membros WHERE idCliente = ?; 
           SELECT ultimoSalario as salarioTitular FROM cadastro WHERE idCliente = ?', [_id, _id, _id], function(err, result){
    if(err) throw err;

    var results = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
    console.log(results);       

    var soma = (results[1][0].salariosMembros + results[2][0].salarioTitular) * 100;
    console.log(soma);

    var data1 = results[0][0];
    console.log(data1);

    res.render('titularDespesas', { id: _id, data: result });

    result = results;

    return result;
    });
},
```

Após pesquisar um pouco mais consegui chegar em um resultado:

Não sei se está da forma mais correta, sei que atendeu a meus propositos:

```
var data = {
  alimentacao : 0,
  agua : 0,
  luz : 0,
  iptu : 0,
  telefone : 0,
  mensalidadesEscolares : 0,
  transporte : 0,
  assistenciaMedica : 0,
  medicamentosContinuos : 0,
  totalDespesas : 0,
  rendaBruta : 0,
  rendaLiquida : 0,
  nMembros : 0,
  rendaPerCapita : 0
}

var valor;

if(**results[0]** == ''){
  valor = data;
}else{
  valor = results[0][0];
}
```

Vlw pessoal!

Comment: O que é `input(value="#{data[0][0].alimentacao || 0}")`? Está usando EJS como engine?

Comment: Qual a necessidade de `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));`?

Comment: @LucasCosta Estou usando Express e Jade

Comment: @RafaelMafra: Sem o JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)); os arrays retornam com uma configuração diferente, assim:
[ [], [ RowDataPacket { nNomes: 0, salariosMembros: null } ], [ RowDataPacket { salarioTitular: null } ] ]

Comment: Acredito que uma opção é chegar no JADE se a propriedade existe, mais ou menos isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070841/jade-template-engine-how-to-check-if-a-variable-exists

Comment: @LucasCosta, o grande problema é selecionar a propriedade do objeto. Isso que não estou conseguindo. Essa forma que você mostrou deu certo se eu usar da seguinte maneira: data[0][0] porque existe os arrays 0.

Porém, são varios campos inputs e cada um com seu dado. Nesse caso, eu preciso acessar da seguinte forma: data[0][0].alimentacao, data[0][0].agua e etc.

Só que o array continua vazio, não existe a propriedade alimentacao, então da erro dizendo que a propriedade alimentacao é indefinido.

Answer (score 1):

É responsabilidade do programador conferir se os dados que ele quer acessar existem. Usando `if` ou alguma outra estrutura para conferir isso.

Comment: Realmente, após pesquisar um pouco mais verifiquei que estava tentando buscar dados além do permitido, por isso não conseguia estruturar nenhuma condição.

Não sei se está da forma mais correta, sei que atendeu a meus propositos:

var data = {
        alimentacao : 0,
 agua : 0,
 luz : 0,
 iptu : 0,
 telefone : 0,
 mensalidadesEscolares : 0,
 transporte : 0,
 assistenciaMedica : 0,
 medicamentosContinuos : 0,
 totalDespesas : 0,
 rendaBruta : 0,
 rendaLiquida : 0,
 nMembros : 0,
 rendaPerCapita : 0
}

var valor;
if(results[0] == '') valor = data;
valor = results[0][0];

Comment: Obrigado pessoal!!!